# MS Access - Query Using GROUPBY - Show Groups with Zero Values

Tags: ms-access, group-by, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT i.[Race / Ethnicity], NZ(Count(i.[Race / Ethnicity]),0) AS [Count Ethnicity]
FROM Information AS i 
LEFT JOIN Visits AS v 
ON i.[Customer ID] = v.[Customer ID]
WHERE (Month(v.[Visit Date]) = [Forms]![Report Generator]![month_box_rpt] 
       AND Year(v.[Visit Date]) = [Forms]![Report Generator]! 
       [year_box_rpt]) and (Month(i.[Signup Date]) = [Forms]![Report Generator]![month_box_rpt] AND Year(i.[Signup Date]) = [Forms]![Report Generator]![year_box_rpt])
GROUP BY (i.[Race / Ethnicity]);
```

It takes month (`[month_box_rpt]`) and year (`[year_box_rpt]`) values from a form and compares to month and year values for a value in one of the tables (`[Visit Date]`) and returns a count of people of different ethnicities (`GROUP BY (i.[Race / Ethnicity])`).

The query works.  However if there are zero records that meet the specified criteria I get a blank return when the query is run.

How can I get a result that has each of my universe of ethnicities and a zero value if there are no people of that ethnicity that meet the criteria?

Example:

```
Race / Ethnicity         Count

    Asian                 0
    Black                 0 
    White                 0
```

or (if some groups have values):

```
Race / Ethnicity         Count

    Asian                 0
    Black                 3 
    White                 2
```

Right now the above query returns:

```
Race / Ethnicity         Count
```

or:

```
Race / Ethnicity         Count

    Black                 3 
    White                 2
```

I believe it involves a sub-query and have tried several but haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: Either you need dummy records for each ethnicity/date with 0 value or join (LEFT or RIGHT, not INNER) GROUP BY query to table of ethnicities.

Answer (score 1):

Left Join the results of your aggregate query with another table or query that contains a single row for each of the Ethnicity values and nothing else.. join on Ethnicity = Ethnicity

Comment: I created a new table Ethnicities with a field Ethnicity with each ethnicity. The only thing in that table are two fields `ID` (which is an auto id) and `Ethnicity`.  I left joined the new table to the existing query: `LEFT JOIN Ethnicities AS e ON i.[Race / Ethnicity] = e.[Ethnicity]` .  The empty GROUP BY ethnicities still aren't shown and the count is not shown either.  Same result as without the table and join.  What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: Left join, by definition, will contain ALL rows from the table mentioned on the left side of the join statement, so that should be your new table. So, easy way, save your working aggregate query. Make sure one of the fields in that aggregate query is the ethnicity. Then do: select * from NewEthnicityTable n left join SavedAggregateQuery s on n.ethnicity = s.ethnicity

Comment: Note: the missing ethnicities from the aggregate query will have null values after the join, not 0. There are a few ways you can get 0 in there if/when you get the join working properly.

Comment: So I have the join working as you recommend in your first comment.  I've tried numerous things to try and get the unmatched (NULL) from the newEthnicities table that I LEFT JOINed the original query to.   Tried NZ(count(*)) and NZ(Count(i.[Race / Ethnicity]) but doesn't work.  Some other things too.  So close but just can't lock it.

Comment: I think I would need to see the exact structure of the tables involved and the output from your aggregate query to help further. It sounds like you don't have a field in the aggregate query that can match easily to the new ethnicity table you created. If you update your question to include those details, perhaps I can give the queries or suggest how to modify the tables.

Comment: There should not be any where conditions placed on the left join to the new ethnicity table, only inside the aggregate query. Maybe you are filtering the null results out of the final answer with something in the where clauses, It's hard to say, the way I am imagining this problem it should work as I described, so something is off.

Comment: Try looking a this answer, seems like it might be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715135/need-simple-sql-direction