# Need Simple SQL direction

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a Ado SQL statement for my Access table and I'm getting the wrong results.

Employee Table

```
ID      Name    DriverID
1   Alex    1
2   Tom     2
3   Trevor  3
4   PHIL    0
5   Gina    4
```

Vehicle Table

```
ID  PLATE   EMPLOYEEID  INSERVICE
1   123XYZ  1       N
2   456GFR  2       Y
3   TFV4FG  3       Y
4   F6GK7D  4       Y
5   GEY7GH  1       Y
```

I want result of All employes and to display the Vehcicle info if they are assigned to it.

```
Result should be
Name    Plate
Alex    GEY7GH
Tom     456GFR
Trevor  TFV4FG
PHIL    
Gina    F6GK7D

SELECT Employee.ID, Employee.FirstName, Vehicles.Plate, Vehicles.InService
FROM Employee LEFT JOIN Vehicles ON Employee.ID = Vehicles.DriverID
WHERE (((Vehicles.InService)=True));
```

Does not display PHIL who is not assigned to a vehicle.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is turning your left join into an inner join. Move the condition from the where to the join conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition inside the join, making sure to use parentheses to avoid problems when joining with constants or anything but simple equals:

```
SELECT Employee.ID, Employee.FirstName, Vehicles.Plate, Vehicles.InService
FROM Employee LEFT JOIN Vehicles ON (Employee.ID = Vehicles.DriverID AND Vehicles.InService = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a normal database, you would move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.  But I don't think that MS Access supports this:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.FirstName, v.Plate, v.InService
FROM Employee as e LEFT JOIN
     Vehicles as v
     ON e.ID = v.DriverID AND v.InService = True;
```

An alternative is a subquery:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.FirstName, v.Plate, v.InService
FROM Employee as e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT v.*
      FROM Vehicles as v
      WHERE v.InService = True
     ) as v
     ON e.ID = v.DriverID ;
```

Comment: Access does support constants in the `ON` clause, as long as you use parentheses.

Comment: @ErikA . . . Do you know if that is a (relatively) new feature?  I am pretty sure that long ago it did not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's at least since 2007 (before that I rarely used Access) but the parentheses can get tricky.

Comment: @ErikA . . . FYI.  I'm not the only one who thinks that MS Access doesn't support this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543466/access-left-join-with-multiple-criteria.

Comment: Of course, it's a common misconception. I think I've even spread it in my starting days as an Access developer, because I got taught it didn't. But one can simply test and see it does work.

Answer (score 0):

From the above tables, it looks like the DriverID Column in employee table aligns with the EmployeeID column in the vehicles table and the issue is the `on` clause in the join.

```
SELECT 
          Employee.ID
          ,Employee.FirstName
          ,Vehicles.Plate
          ,Vehicles.InService
FROM 
         Employee 
         LEFT JOIN Vehicles      ON Employee.DRIVERID = Vehicles.EMPLOYEEID
WHERE 
         (((Vehicles.InService)=True));
```